# how can i get properties in static class

Tags: java, spring

```
 static class PushConfig{

    @Value("${jpush.mq.appKey}")
    private String appKeyMQ;
 }
```

like this, I want to get config in inner Class,it's not work

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with this code:

```
public static anyName = yourClass
```

Then you can use anyName.anyMethod(...) to use a method